# Prove that series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be convergent series of complex terms. Prove there exist unbounded sequance $(b_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ of positive terms such that series $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n\cdot b_n$ is convergent

I thougth that when $|a_{k_n}| \le\frac{1}{4^n}$ then $b_{k_n}=2^n+1$ else $b_n=1$ but I'm not sure if it works

Comment: Yes, that works. I imagine, though, the problem should have required that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n=\infty$.

Comment: but I have question here what is the difference if the series would has the real terms from complex in this example. And I'm not sure about my explanation, can I say that new series converge since if $|a_n|>\frac{1}{4^n}$ then we have just series $a_n$ which is convergent and when we have $|a_n \le \frac{1}{4^n}|$ then the general term is in form $\frac{2^n+1}{4^n}$ which is convergent since it's geometric series, is it correct or not ?